# Android Camera Photo Thumbnail Orientation

Tags: android, camera, orientation, photo

We have been using a bunch of code that uses the camera with the desired end result, but I want to get to the bottom of this with clean code. I'm simply following the Android docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView) verbatim, and getting a rotated thumbnail. Below is the code, please find the working project in [this branch of my Bitbucket repository](https://bitbucket.org/gazialankus/androidcameraplay/src/68524c81f8ec4688ae168ffe02a01bfb6021266f/?at=thumbnail-sideways).

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");

        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        view.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
```

I know that this is just the thumbnail. But it seems the thumbnail is completely useless, unless you get the full file and read the exif info from that.

I know that StackOverflow says "get the exif rotation from the full image file and rotate the actual bitmap before recompressing it into another jpg file". But isn't this a little too much unnecessary computation? What good is the thumbnail if it's useless by itself without getting the orientation from the full file?

Am I missing something?

Comment: "But isn't this a little too much unnecessary computation?" -- you are invoking a third-party camera app. By and large, it can do whatever it wants. Ideally, it adheres to the protocol specifications, in this case for `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Since `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not specify the orientation of the thumbnail bitmap *or* the full-size image, you would need to assume that either could be in any orientation, and there is no requirement for any EXIF headers in the full-size image to help you. If you do not like this, do not use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: I'm using the Android Emulator with the Google's camera app, but I get your point. I won't try to make sense of the details with my assumptions and use a library such as https://github.com/google/cameraview or https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2 Oh wait, the second one is yours! Nice coincidence.

Comment: The craptastic `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` protocol is why I wrote the library. Trust me, I would be *far* happier if either `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` were better or it wasn't such a pain to use the camera APIs directly.